# Display XML in tree view

Tags: c#, xml, select, uwp, tree

I have following XML Structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootnode>
  <Level 1>
    <Level 2>
      <Level 3>
      </Level 3>
    </Level 2>
    <Level 2>
      <Level 3>
      </Level 3>
    </Level 2>
  </Level 1>
  <Level 1>
    <Level 2>
      <Level 3>
      </Level 3>
    </Level 2>
  </Level 1>
</rootnode>
```

I Want to Display this Xml Stucture in a Treeview, 
As best should be **XDocument** used for the this.

Can someone help me?

Comment: "only the Name of the Level 1,2,3" but your sample only has names on level 5. Make it more clear. Include names you want and names you don't want, specify the expected output.

Comment: I Want the Name Level1 , Level2 , Level3 this should be the result

Comment: Edit the question with clearer specs and examples.

Comment: what should i edit ? I want as result a Array list with strings, in this example it should look like = Level 1,Level2,Level3,Level 1,Level2,Level3,Level 1,Level2,Level3 ....

Comment: Start by fixing the XML (`<Level 1>` is not valid). Your open/close tags don't match so the names do not correspond to the actual levels.  Then list the actual outcome, and be clear about possible variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a recursive algorithm :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication15
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int MAX_LEVEL = 3;
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;

            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
            newNode.Text = root.Name.LocalName;
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
            int level = 1;
            AddRecursive(root, newNode, level);

            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }
        public void AddRecursive(XElement element, TreeNode parent, int level)
        {
            foreach (XElement child in element.Elements())
            {
                TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
                newNode.Text = child.Name.LocalName;
                parent.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                if (level < MAX_LEVEL)
                {
                    AddRecursive(child, newNode, level + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```